# Bootstrap typography display font class render different text sizes on my local web development env

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, fonts

I am just trying to simply use display-1 class from bootstrap 4 in my website. What surprises me is that the font size on bootstrap official website render display-1 as 6rem size where as on my local web it renders as 5rem.

1. I am not creating any custom css just default bootstrap.
2. I have verified them via inspecting dev tool on respective elements in both places(bootstrap & local website)
3. Both screenshots were taken on the same screen.

Here is the screenshot.

**BootStrap**

[image]

**Local Web**

[image]

Comment: are you using the same version of bootstrap? looks like your local one has media queries where as the live one doesn't (or your browser size is different so the media queries kick in)

Comment: @Pete yes I am using their latest version via CDN. Yes I noticed that too which I didn't understand either. why it is rendering under media queries on my local web, see my third point. I mentioned it because of this only so that there is no confusion regarding the screen size.